# Skipped 46 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android, for-loop, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to use the RecyclerView and put eight images in the adapter dynamically. I have also the titles of each image so i create 2 arrays and with a for loop with multiple condition i can set what i want. It works but not as i want. Infact i get in the log:

```
Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

And the scroll of the list has a very strong lag. How can i solve? This is the code

```
public class ImageAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<GridItem> mItems;
    private static WallpaperManager wallpaper;

    String[] title = {
            "Material1",
            "Material2",
            "Wallpaper1",
            "Wallpaper2",
            "Wallpaper3",
            "Wallpaper4",
            "Wallpaper5",
            "Wallpaper6",
            "Wallpaper7"
        };

    private static int[] sDrawables = { 
        R.drawable.material, 
        R.drawable.materialuno, 
        R.drawable.materialdue,
        R.drawable.materialtre,
        R.drawable.materialquattro, 
        R.drawable.materialcinque, 
        R.drawable.materialsei, 
        R.drawable.materialsette, 
        R.drawable.materialotto
        };

    public ImageAdapter() {
        super();
        mItems = new ArrayList<GridItem>();

        for (int i=0, j=0; i < title.length && j < sDrawables.length; i++, j++) {

            GridItem wallTitle = new GridItem();
            wallTitle.setName(title[i]);
            wallTitle.setThumbnail(sDrawables[j]);
            mItems.add(wallTitle);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_grid_layout, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        final GridItem nature = mItems.get(i);
        viewHolder.tvspecies.setText(nature.getName());
        viewHolder.imgThumbnail.setImageResource(nature.getThumbnail());

        viewHolder.imgThumbnail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("CLick",nature.toString());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return mItems.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public ImageView imgThumbnail;
        public TextView tvspecies;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgThumbnail = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
            tvspecies = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_species);
        }
    }
}
```

Edited with entire adapter

Comment: Please post the entire adapter, notably your binding code.

Comment: Ok done, i posted the entire adapter

Comment: OK, the code looks fine. How big are those drawable resources, in terms of resolution? You refer to them as "wallpaper" -- if those are large images, simply loading them the first time will be slow. You might want to package smaller thumbnails and use them for the grid.

Comment: is it possible do it? i mean only loading them the first time will be slow? mmh btw this is only a test.the real walls will be from web so that array of drawable will be an array of links or a json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the real walls will be from web so that array of drawable will be an array of links or a json

You *absolutely* do not want to be loading full-size wallpaper images to use for thumbnails in a grid. That will be very slow, and you will run out of heap space.

For your short-term tests, I'd just prepare some thumbnails using a graphics editor, then use those.

For your "for realz" app, where your wallpapers are downloaded, you will want to use a third-party library, like Picasso or Universal Image Loader, that can load the images in the background, downsample them to thumbnail size, and so on. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/HTTP/Picasso) demonstrates `ListView` with Picasso (reading in Stack Overflow questions). [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RecyclerView/VideoList) demonstrates `RecyclerView` with Universal Image Loader (reading in video thumbnails from the videos on the device).

Comment: Thanks, your explanation was so clear. You're right btw and time ago i used  Universal Image Loader and it works very well. Now, think about my app, which could be the best way to proceed? I have a server, so i could create a json in which i could write all images and link of them and then in app retrieve everything and with the library image loader put the image from the links of the json right? But the task for the json have i to write it in the RecyclerView adapter? It's first time i use RecyclerView..

Comment: @End.Game: "But the task for the json have i to write it in the RecyclerView adapter?" -- that is really beyond the scope of your original question and this answer. And the details of when and where you download the JSON depend a lot on the nature of your app. Having the `RecyclerView.Adapter` do the download would not be one of my recommended options.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue/error-message with very long delays using RecyclerView.  I read on SO different answers about thread optimization, adapter optimization, etc.

Finally in tracing down where the issue started, I found out this Xml in `TextView` was the culprit

```
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLength="300"
            android:maxLines="5"
```

Removing all that and just using standard values for width and height, the issue for me was resolved

Comment: what are "standard" values?

Comment: It's been a while, but looks like by *standard* I meant like `wrap_content` .. vs. something a bit more tricky like `0dp`